# Hide 6 columns (3 groups of 2) Script - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet that I want to automatically hide columns A, B, M, N, Y & Z on.

I've used the script below.  The Menu appears & functions.

The 'Show' option shows the desired columns, but shows an error message "Those columns are out of bounds."

The 'Hide' option hides too much.  It hides columns 1,2.  The problem occurs here; it then hides everything from column M-Z.  All I can see is A-L and then AA onwards.  It has the same error message "Those columns are out of bounds"

```
function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name: "Show", functionName: "showColumns"}, {name: "Hide", 
  functionName: "hideColumns"}]
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Show/Hide", menu);
}

function showColumns() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.showColumns(1,2);
  sheet.showColumns(13,14);
  sheet.showColumns(25,26);
}

function hideColumns() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.hideColumns(1,2);
  sheet.hideColumns(13,14);
  sheet.hideColumns(25,26);
}
```

I'm a novice to scripts, so am struggling to get this to work.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

HideColumns and showColumns works like hideColumns(columnIndex, numColumns). So to show or hide 2 columns you need the start column and the number of columns to hide, not the other column number. For example change:

```
sheet.hideColumns(13,14);
```

to:

sheet.hideColumns(13,2);